# Reply to two addresses?

Tags: marketing-cloud, bestpractice, triggered-send, send-definition

I've been asked to research solutions to a scenario where when a subscriber replies to an email it goes to the sender an additional 3rd party, without the subscriber having to "reply-all".

My plan to handle this issue would be to use a Sender Profile where replies use a Triggered Send, and have the triggered send deliver to the person the subscriber is replying to, and cc/bcc the 3rd party.

The business need is to notify the 3rd party when a customer replies to a particular piece of mail. Are there better solutions for this request?

Edit: I should mention we are an RMM customer.

Comment: I believe Enterprise Reply Mail Management (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_enterprise_reply_mail_management.htm&type=5) can assist you in this - but the solution is mostly similar to what you mentioned with the triggered send.

Comment: We do use Reply Mail Management, but the trick is to get the email to send to an additional recipient. Doing the triggered send / cc is the way to go, you think?

Comment: Enterprise RMM is different than normal RMM. It is a more granular approach to replies but also requires more technical knowledge and effort.

Comment: One additional question - I'm familiar with setting up triggered sends, but I'm not sure how the customer's email content gets passed into the triggered send email - is it passed as some sort of attribute I can include in the message?

Comment: I believe you would use `%%_replycontent%%` to pass the content from the reply email into your TSD - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks! Can you combine your responses into a single answer for visibility? I'll vote/close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [Enterprise Reply Mail Management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_enterprise_reply_mail_management.htm&type=5) can assist you in this - but the solution is mostly similar to what you mentioned with the triggered send. Enterprise RMM is different than normal RMM. It is a more granular approach to replies but also requires more technical knowledge and effort, so it may not be a solution for everyone.

In order to show the content from the previous email inside your reply TSD, you will need to use the `%%_replycontent%%` [personalization string](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5).